# asp.net Webforms MapPageRoute order of precedence

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I am attempting to use the MapPageRoute feature in Visual Studio 2010 and 
.NET Framework 4.0 with a asp.net webforms application.

What I have noticed is that if I define a page route called "Default" like 
below and the page Default.aspx exists in the project, then the route does 
not work.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "default.aspx", "~/Page2.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "test.aspx", "~/Page2.aspx");
```

If I change the name of the Default.aspx in the project to Default_1.aspx, 
then the route works fine.

There seems to be some order of precedence going on.  Is there a way to make 
my route definitions evaluated first so I don't have to rename my pages to 
use the routing engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a property on the `RouteCollection` called `RouteExistingFiles`, which is set to false by default.  This explains why the Default route doesn't work if you have a default.aspx page.

If you insert `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` before your lines of code, it would make the routes take priority.  I'm not 100% sure whether it would then fall back to files if it couldn't route - I guess it depends on the routes you have set up...

Comment: setting routes.RouteExistingFiles = true did the trick.  thanks.